# "XPath" VS "Linq to Xml"

Tags: c#

Я хочу, чтобы программа работала с файлом *.xml*. Есть какие-то *textBox*, из которых будут браться значения и записываться в файл, к примеру для дальнейшей обработки.

Что лучше использовать для работы с *.xml* файлами *XPath* или *Linq to Xml*?

Читал разные статьи и примеры. Выходит *Linq to Xml* более новый способ, я правильно понимаю? Кроме того, код выглядит более читабельно и он более краток.

Подскажите, что лучше использовать.

Comment: Лучше сериализацию

Comment: Знаете, до нее не дошел, можно подробнее?

Comment: Ну так дойдите, почитайте, XmlSerializer вполне себе просто использовать. Не нужно будет вручную работать с элементами/атрибутами.

Comment: [Сравнительные характеристики XPath и LINQ to XML](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/comparison-of-xpath-and-linq-to-xml)

Comment: XPath - это язык _запросов_, он бесполезен при _создании_ xml. Для создания xml, конечно, берите классы XDocument/XElement, которые относятся к технологии linq2xml.

Comment: А вот когда вы будете _парсить_ xml, тут можно подумать над выбором. В большинстве случаев я бы взял linq2xml. А XPath только в том случае, если нужно в рантайме менять правила разбора. Ведь XPath - это просто строка, которую можно загрузить из конфига или получить от пользователя (из консоли или текстбокса) без перекомпиляции приложения.

Comment: Вот хороший ответ. Коротко и ясно.